# using ffmpeg to stitch together image files, having troubles with audio synchronization

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I'm going to be stitching together images recorded alongside a video, and then use the audio track from the original video.  To make sure things work as expected, I run a simple test that splits a video into images then stitches them back together into the original video:

```
ffmpeg -i '.\Gangnam Style.mp4' -r 30 -s 640x480 -f image2 temp/foo-%07d.jpeg
ffmpeg -f image2 -i temp/foo-%07d.jpeg -r 30 -i '.\Gangnam Style.mp4' -map 0:0 -map 1 test.webm
```

In the resulting output test.webm, the audio is no longer synchronized with the video.  Does anyone know why this would be?  Since I'm use images made from the original video, I'd think the audio should line up perfectly.

Comment: How do you make sure that framerate is the same in the new video as in the original?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work just fine:

```
ffmpeg -r 30 -i temp/foo-%07d.jpeg -i '.\Gangnam Style.mp4' output.webm
```

---

Here's the reason your images weren't aligned with your audio stream.

```
ffmpeg -i '.\Gangnam Style.mp4' -r 30 -s 640x480 -f image2 temp/foo-%07d.jpeg
```

Here you're creating images at 30 fps (`-f image2` isn't needed here).

```
ffmpeg -f image2 -i temp/foo-%07d.jpeg -r 30 -i '.\Gangnam Style.mp4' …
```

Here you're reading images at 25 fps and the MP4 file at 30 fps. The reason for this is that options passed before `-i` apply to that input only. All the options after `-i` are for the next input or are output options.

25 fps are the default for [the `image2` demuxer](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#image2-2) (it's the `-framerate` option, `-r` is a shortcut). Note that `-f image2` is superfluous in your command. I'm also fairly certain the `-map` options can be left out in your case. Usually ffmpeg will map one video and one audio source to the output correctly.